# Oracle 12c, can not chose standard edition when install!

Tags: installation, oracle-12c, windows-server

i'm trying to install Oracle 12c on Windows 2012 R2 ... I get Enterprise Edition option **only**!

**I need to install Standard Edition!**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no Standard Edition released from version 12.1.0.1

Download 12.1.0.2 for Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0):

12.0.1.2 Patch set for Standard Edition its available since Sept 1, 2015 . It's labeled as Oracle Database Standard Edition 2, and it's deployed as a different download installer.

More info: https://blogs.oracle.com/UPGRADE/entry/oracle_12_1_0_22